# How to count elements inside array in Postman test

Tags: postman

I was unable to find correct answer and therefore posting a question.
Return response on Postman is as below:

```
   [
     {
      "AttemptNumber":1,
      "LoginID":test123,
      "CurrentStatus":2
     }
   ]
```

I'm trying to count elements in this array object.
this is what I was doing:

```
   countItems = JSON.pase(responseBody)
       for (var i = 1, l = Object.keys(countItems).length; i <=3){
    }
```

but I keep getting 1. 1 is array but I'm looking for count to be 3.
I'll appreciate your expertise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should log the number of items from each object in the response array:

```js
let res = pm.response.json()

_.each(res, (obj) => {
    console.log(_.keys(obj).length)
})
```

It's using some methods from Lodash, which is one of the built-in libraries.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15

Comment: If that solves the problem, can you accept it as the answer 